# How to decide/determine what kind/genre of world one should build?

Tags: worldbuilding-process

Are there some factors one should ask oneself to determine what kind of genre his world should be?
Im in a situation where i simply have trouble deciding. Whether it's Fantasy, Science-Fiction, Post-apocalyptic, Science fantasy, Cyberpunk, Futuristic etc. etc. 
I want to create a world where superhumans exist. But nothing as massive or/and "ridiculous" like DC or Marvel.

Comment: It might be better fit on http://writers.stackexchange.com - here it seems too opinion based.

Comment: This could be all right for Worldbuilding if you can focus it more. What kind of superhumans? What can they do? How far are you willing to go from science? Are there any themes or issues you want to explore? Are you interested in building a language, geography, a solar system, a city, a society? Are there any parts you don't want to build?

Comment: The being with superhuman should not be able to run in lightspeed or be able to shatter a whole continent with a punch or something like that. The powerlevel should be comparable to something like the God of War (expect for titan scenes), prototype, darksiders series or prince of persia sands of time series.

Comment: Please put additional details directly into your question. You can edit it - and you should, as long as it doesn't invalidate already posted answers.

Comment: Welcome to the site Majini.  This is a question we all have to ask, and frankly is a good conversation to have with other people.  Unfortunately its just not a good fit for the site.  My suggestion would be to hang out a bit gain some rep and then join us in [chat] when you hit the rep required mark.  This is a conversation we would love to work through with  you.

Answer (score 3):

## What kind of story do you want to tell?

Before you run off and create a world, you need to take a step back and ask yourself:

*"What is the **story** I want to tell?"*

If you create a world but have no story for it, then you have written [a role-playing campaign setting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_campaign_settings), like Forgotten Realms or Hârn. This is all good and well if this is what you want to do; if you want to cater to **players** or to other authors in search of a setting. But there is nothing to be had in it from the perspective of a **reader**.

My favourite example of A World In Search Of A Story would be the film [Ultra Violet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet_(film)). Kurt Wimmer created a superbly interesting world. It is well thought out, coherent and with quite exciting things going on in it. From a world-building perspective, Wimmer has succeeded admirably.

**The film however is absolute shite.** Why? Because it has no story. There is no tale to be told, no issue to explore, no relatible struggle to bite your nails to while the hero faces adversity and hardship to win through at the end.

So before you create a world you need work out what the **story** is that you want to tell. From that you can then figure out what kind of world might be good to frame it in; that can provide the tools and plot elements that you need for the story.

Answer (score 0):

I would pay attention to two things in such genres:  what do you want to write about, and what limits are you willing to place on yourself.

First off, note that you don't actually have to pick a genre at all.  You can make up your own genre, right on the spot.  You're the world builder, have at it!

The advantage of picking a genre is that you can pick up a vast body of content which others have explored and fleshed out.  Want to play with octopuses?  Steam-punk *loves* their cephalopods, and the community is more than happy to provide you with great ideas along those lines.  Want high magic?  The fantasy world is a realm where readers are already prepped to see magic that would be hard to swallow in other realms.  Choose a realm which inspires you.

The other side of the coin with picking a genre is that each genre has its fundamental rules.  None of these rules are truly set in stone (nor should they be!), but it becomes harder to sell your story as "part of the genre" if you break them.  These rules really exist to shape the genre and to give writers some structure to work with.  Bend the rules if you feel you should, but always respect them while you're doing so.

In other words, your life will be much easier if you pick a genre whose rules don't feel too confining to you.  The less confining they are, the less likely you are to have to bend them, and the less you run the risk of upsetting the fans who were told what genre they were reading.

Obviously such rules are not written down, but I can give my opinions about them here.  Feel free to have your own opinions:

- Fantasy - In the world of fantasy, technology plays a minor role.  Rarely will you see a fantasy world which focuses on the technology and its development.  Magic is often found here as a replacement.
- Science-Fiction - The opposite of fantasy, science fiction typically comes with an expectation that everything you present has some reasonable scientific backing.  You don't have to explain everything (as Arthur C. Clarke famously stated, "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic."), but you are expected to hand wave the explanations in a sciency fashion.  Science fiction is typically very picky about consistency.  If you claim the science works one way, and then change your mind mid-story for plot reasons, science fiction readers are less forgiving than others.
- Post-apocalyptic - Everything's broken!  In these worlds, you're obliged to deal with the reality of all of our complex devices and our complex societies have come apart at the seams.  If you want fancy devices or powerful governments, you typically have to explain how these things managed to rise from the ashes.
- Science fantasy - I'm not too familiar with this genre.  Feel free to make up your own rules!
- Cyberpunk - The power of the computer is almost overpowering.  Humans are typically struggling to try to retain their humanity, or have given up on the process entirely.

If any of those descriptions says "this doesn't feel like a limiting factor at all for my world," then there's a good chance that that genre is a good match to start from.  At worst, you can always stop what you're doing and invent a new sub-genre in the spot to better fit your story!

Comment: Science-fantasy is regarded as the bastard child science-fiction. Looks like science-fiction, but plays by fantasy rules. More science-fiction is science-fantasy than the ideologically pure would care to admit. Fantasy allows for the impossible and the plain contrariwise to reality to be part of the furniture.Think more *Alice in Wonderland* *Lord of the Rings*. Too often faux-medieval fantasies are regarded as fantasy. They're only a small subgenre of a much bigger literary beastie.

Comment: Think Star Wars: it looks like science but it's definitely fantasy. In general most of big Hollywood "science fiction" productions are actually science-fantasy.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to force our creativity to exist within set limitations imposed by genre or anything else isn't helpful to being creative. It's stifling. As long as your world is internally consistent, you can do what you want. Crossing genre boundaries is fine. Genre mostly matters during marketing, when you can just say it's a mix of this and that genre. Being able to put your book into more than one sub-category of Amazon and other retailers is a plus.

If you're early in your conception, genre expectations can be especially stifling. And who wants to be stifled or follow expectations?

I recommend doing what you want.